# angular-ui-router traceur controller assignation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, traceur

I am trying to assign the controller to the state in ui-router. The controller is compiled by traceur.

State assignation looks like this:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('form', {
       url: '/form'
     , templateUrl: 'views/form.html'
     , controller: 'FormController as Form'
   })
```

Compiled controller looks like this:

```
var FormController = function FormController($stateParams, $http) {
this.data = {};
  this._stateParams = $stateParams;
  this._http = $http;
  this.formTemplate = "";
};
($traceurRuntime.createClass)(FormController, {
  submit: function() {
    console.log('submitted');
  }
}, {});
```

I obviously receive a runtime error which says that FormController is not a function. Is there a way around it? Any other solution?

Comment: Not a function... usually means, that you did not registered that with angular. Check twice if there is `.controller('FormController', FormController)`.  also, the state def should not contain braces: `controller: 'FormController as Form'`

Comment: Sorry, wrong paste, was trying different things. Yes, braces are not there and FormController is assigned. In fact, if I remove `var FromController = ` from the compiled file, everything is working as it should.

Comment: It would be nice to see more of your code... and as it really is ;) even better... some plunker, not working one... to be fixed... Why? Becuase "is not a function" **simply almost alway means** that the **`.controller('FormController', ...`** was not called

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/aHUHtkHQwUr0Vfrfw2X8?p=preview Pluner with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/5SJthSK85qzVbTZNCxXn?p=preview) - I just changed the order of definition

```
var app = angular.module('brokenApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(ApplicationConfig)
; 

// controller def in JS world
var FormController = function ($sc, $stateParams, $http) {
  $sc.title = "hello from scope";
  this.title = "hello from controller";
  this.data = {};
  this._stateParams = $stateParams;
  this._http = $http;
  this.formTemplate = ""; 
}; 

// DI
FormController.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http']

// controller injection into angular
app.controller('FormController', FormController);
```

There is new `form.html`

```
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<h3>$scope.title: </h3>
{{title}}

<h3>controller.title: </h3>
{{Form.title}}
```

Instead of this [original code](http://plnkr.co/edit/aHUHtkHQwUr0Vfrfw2X8?p=preview):

```
angular.module('brokenApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(ApplicationConfig)
.controller('FormController', FormController);
//# sourceURL=app-wrapper.js
"use strict";
var FormController = function FormController($stateParams, $http) {
  this.data = {};
  this._stateParams = $stateParams;
  this._http = $http;
  this.formTemplate = "";
};
```

Check the working version [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5SJthSK85qzVbTZNCxXn?p=preview)

Comment: Great to see that sir ;) Enjoy amazing UI-Router ;)